# Runtime exception when trying to reorder an NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmutablearray

I have a UITableViewController that shows a list of user defined favorites that are stored in Core Data. When the table view loads, the managed objects are placed in a mutable array. To construct the mutable array I use the following static method (which is in a separate class):

```
+(NSMutableArray*)getAllFavorites{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[FavesDataModel sharedDataModel] mainContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchReq = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortByIndex = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"index" ascending:YES];
    [fetchReq setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByIndex]];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:[Favorite entityName] inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchReq setEntity:entity];

    NSError *err = nil;
    return (NSMutableArray*)[context executeFetchRequest:fetchReq error:&err];
}
```

In my table view I need to allow users to reorder rows. I have verified that my mutable array of favorite managed objects is complete, however, when I try to remove an object at a given index, an exception is thrown at run-time (-[_PFArray removeObjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance). Here is the code causing the exception:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
    [self setEditing:YES animated:YES];        
    NSInteger rowIndex = fromIndexPath.row;
    Favorite *fave = [allFavoriteObjects objectAtIndex:rowIndex];

    [allFavoriteObjects removeObjectAtIndex:rowIndex]; // exception thrown here
    [allFavoriteObjects insertObject:fave atIndex:toIndexPath.row];
}
```

Any suggestions? Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSManagedObjectContext's executeFetchRequest might be returning a **immutable** array. Try this instead.

```
return [[context executeFetchRequest:fetchReq error:&err] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: The `(NSMutableArray*)` cast is not necessary.

Comment: Is the cast necessary when using mutableCopy?

Comment: ok. I ll remove it. It is not necessary. Since we can be sure, that the _id_ is actually a NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
return (NSMutableArray*)[context executeFetchRequest:fetchReq error:&err];
```

Try using

```
return [[context executeFetchRequest:fetchReq error:&err] mutableCopy];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use auxiliar NSMutableArray when do this, because the `allFavoriteObjects` is used in your class, and various methods from tableview access to them.